# Npapi set timer function

Tags: firefox, plugins, npapi, nsapi

I'm still running Firefox 2.0.0. For backward compatibility reasons
I'd like to know weather there is a easy way to ***replace*** the

NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall, NPN_ScheduleTimer

mechanism that the newer npapi supplies. 
The only solution that I would come up with is to evaluate a 
javascript "setTimeout" that would call the plugin then ...
-- KE
What I'm working on is at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sockplugin/

Some seem to call it nsapi, so I add the keyword here too: nsapi

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to tie into the HWND.  for set timer, just use a windows timer on the HWND, and for async call, post a message to the hwnd.  the HWND message loop runs on the UI thread with javascript and the browser.

FireBreath uses this approach, but I don't believe it supports Firefox 2 because ff2 is quite old at this point and is missing a lot of features used by FireBreath.  Still, you could borrow some code.